Intent.createChooser automatically hides statusbar and causes layout jumping on some devices
Each time I open the intentChooser, the statusbar automatically hides and the view jumps. This only happens on some devices (Samsung S22 in this case) but no on the Pixel 3a emulator.
You can find a screen recording here: https://i.imgur.com/wSNFJg0.mp4
I created a new project and was able to replicate the issue, so it doesn't seem like there is some custom theme or anything from my project that is causing the issue.
I have looked into display cutouts, insets and most things I can think of. I tried overriding activity animations, creating a transparent "fake" activity to launch the intent but everything results in the same issue occurring.
Does anyone know what causes this issue?

Can you post code ?

It's just an intentChooser. 'startActivity(Intent.createChooser(...'

If you are using compose and edgeToEdge is enabled, you can use Modifier.displayCutoutPadding() or Modifier.safeDrawingPadding() to get rid of this issue.
Do not try to apply the padding yourself by using WindowInsets.displayCutout.asPaddingValues() because it will not work.
